# How do i make the background-image visible in my css

Tags: css, background-image

I have three files in my public_html root:

```
public_html:
  index.htm 
  deer.jpg 
  style.css
```

In the css.style i have

```
body{
    background-image:url('deer.jpg');
}
```

In the index.htm, i have

```
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    <title>AAA</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Filling the Gap betwwen ASIC Design Education and Industry</h1>
<h2>Interview Questions/Industry Case Study</h2>

<ul>
    <li><a href="asic/index.htm">Asic Design</a></li>  
    <li><a href="rental/rental.htm">Rental Management</a></li>  
</ul>
<p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why the picture doesn't show up in my webpage?

Comment: Check if the image is being loaded in the first place. If you are getting 404, that means browser couldn't download the image, and hence will ignore the `background-image` property.

Comment: @Prajwal Sorry, new to html. How do i check whether image has been loaded? I don't see 404 on the page itself. Do i inspect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `background: url('deer.jpg') no-repeat;` instead of `background-image`

Comment: it is the same. No display of pic

Comment: Like @Prajwal said, check and see if the image is being loaded. I would use Inspect Tool depending on your browser

Comment: I use chrome. After inspect, in the source tab, i only see htm and css file, but not the deer.jpg. Is this expected? If not, how do i make my image uploaded there? From my web host portal, i can see the deer.jpg residing in my folder.

Comment: When you are in Inspect, click on the <body> tag and on the right side you should see your styles. The body should have your background url. right click on that link and open up in a new tab. If your deer picture doesn't show, then the image isn't loaded correctly

Comment: I open inspect, click body tag, style appears below. It is strange that the style doesn't mention css at al or the background-image command linel.  It has 

body{
  display: block;
  margin: 8px;
}